# Binding DataGrid to Matrix

Tags: wpf, mvvm

При изменении размеров матрицы (включая создание новых заголовков для строк и столбцов) вылетает ошибка в конвертере к dataGrid (выход за пределы массива) и изменения значений в dataGrid не изменяют матрицу в VM, та же проблема с CurrentCell (не реагирует на изменения в View).
Пробовал делать через [Gu.Wpf.DataGrid2D](https://github.com/GuOrg/Gu.Wpf.DataGrid2D#with-headers), не получилось.

View:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:VM="clr-namespace:ExcelApp.ViewModels"
    x:Class="ExcelApp.View.MainWindow"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:ExcelApp.ViewModels.Converters"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <VM:MainWindowViewModels/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <converters:MatrixToDataViewConverter x:Key="matrixToDataViewConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="41"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DataGrid Margin="10" SelectionUnit="Cell" SelectionMode="Single" CurrentCell="{Binding CurrentCell}" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False">
        <DataGrid.ItemsSource>
            <MultiBinding Mode="TwoWay" Converter="{StaticResource matrixToDataViewConverter}">
                <Binding Path="ColumnHeaders"/>
                <Binding Path="RowHeaders"/>
                <Binding Path="Values"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </DataGrid.ItemsSource>
    </DataGrid>

    <Button Content="Построить" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="281,0,0,11" Grid.Row="1" Width="74" Height="21" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Command="{Binding GenerateCommand}"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="70,0,0,10" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="73" Height="21" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
             Text="{Binding ColumnsCount}"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="203,0,0,10" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="73" Height="21" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
             Text="{Binding RowsCount}"/>
    <Label Content="Столбцы" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,10" Grid.Row="1" Width="60" Height="21" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    <Label Content="Строки" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="148,0,0,10" Grid.Row="1" Width="55" Height="21" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>

</Grid>
```

VM:

```
public class MainWindowViewModels : DependencyObject
{ 
    public MainWindowViewModels()
    {
        _Table = new Table(10, 10);
        Values = _Table.Values; // string[][]
        RowHeaders = _Table.RowNames; // string[]
        ColumnHeaders = _Table.ColumnNames; // string[]
    }

    private Table _Table { get; set; }

    public string CurrentCell
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(CurrentCellProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CurrentCellProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentCellProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentCell", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindowViewModels), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string[] RowHeaders
    {
        get { return (string[])GetValue(RowHeadersProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RowHeadersProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RowHeadersProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("RowHeaders", typeof(string[]), typeof(MainWindowViewModels), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string[] ColumnHeaders
    {
        get { return (string[])GetValue(ColumnHeadersProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColumnHeadersProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnHeadersProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ColumnHeaders", typeof(string[]), typeof(MainWindowViewModels), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string[][] Values
    {
        get { return (string[][])GetValue(ValuesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValuesProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValuesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Values", typeof(string[][]), typeof(MainWindowViewModels), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public int ColumnsCount { get; set; }
    public int RowsCount { get; set; }

    private RelayCommand _GenerateCommand;
    public RelayCommand GenerateCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return this._GenerateCommand ??
              (this._GenerateCommand = new RelayCommand(obj =>
              {
                  _Table = new Table(RowsCount, ColumnsCount);
                  Values = _Table.Values; // string[][]
                  RowHeaders = _Table.RowNames; // string[]
                  ColumnHeaders = _Table.ColumnNames; // string[]
              }
              ));
        }
    }
}
```

Converter:

```
public class MatrixToDataViewConverter: IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();
            var col = values[0] as string[];
            var row = values[1] as string[];
            var vals = values[2] as string[][];
            myDataTable.Columns.Add("-"); 

            foreach (string value in col)
                myDataTable.Columns.Add(value);

            for (int i = 0; i < row.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] temp = new string[1 + vals[i].Count()];
                vals[i].CopyTo(temp, 1);
                temp[0] = row[i];
                myDataTable.Rows.Add(temp);
            }

            return myDataTable.DefaultView;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = (value as DataView).Table;

            var colums = new string[dataTable.Columns.Count];
            var rows = new string[dataTable.Rows.Count];
            var vals = new string[dataTable.Rows.Count][];

            for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
                colums[i] = dataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName;
            for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                rows[i] = dataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[0] as string;

            for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                vals[i] = new string[dataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray.Length - 1];
                for (int j = 1; j < dataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray.Length; j++)
                    vals[i][j] = dataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[j] as string;
            }

            return new object[3] { colums, rows, vals };
        }

    }
```

Comment: Жесть какая... Что такое `Table`?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Класс где создаются заполненные: RowHeaders[], ColumnHeaders[], Values[][]